# Can I restore old MultiBit wallet with receive address and password?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, multibit, multibit-hd

I have the multibit receive address and the password, from maybe 2014 or so.  The actual wallet is on a drive I will have to have recovered.  Is there any way to recover with and/or without having the drive recovered?

Comment: I guess you didn't make backups and did not export your private keys and put them somewhere safe? Is that so?

Answer (score 1):

There is no relationship between the password and the wallet itself.

Without the wallet file the password is of no use to you.